# How to parse values from chronometer (android)?

Tags: java, android, time, chronometer, elapsedtime

I am currently trying to create an android application for which I need the time elapsed in seconds since clicking the start button until clicking the stop button. Currently I have a timer which uses the following code in the java class:

```
//on start timer
public void startTimer(View view){
    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    myChronometer.start();
}

//on stop timmer
public void stopTimer(View view){
    myChronometer.stop();
}
```

followed by the below code in the xml file for the same class:

```
    <Chronometer
    [...]
    android:id="@+id/chronometer" />

<Button
    android:text="Stop"
    [...]
    android:onClick="stopTimer"/>

<Button
    android:text="Start"
    [...]
    android:onClick="startTimer" />
```

Is there any way I could pass the time elapsed (in sec) using the chronometer to another method in the same java class?

Comment: I am pretty sure that any reasonable Chronometer class has a method that returns you the elapsed time. What prevents you from calling that method?

Comment: @GhostCat honestly... I am not sure what that method is :)

Comment: wow from the docs it looks like Chronometer class does not have a method that return the elapsed time...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there is not method that returns the value ([check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html)) but you can compute it yourself easily:

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase()
```

if you need to access the time after you've stopped the chronometer you can do something like this

```
private long timerTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

//on start timer
public void startTimer(View view){
    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    myChronometer.start();
    timerTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
}       

//on stop timmer
public void stopTimer(View view){
    myChronometer.stop();
    timerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
}

private long getTimerTime(){
    if(timerTime == Long.MIN_VALUE){
        return SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
    }

    return timerTime;
}
```

Comment: Hi @lelloman thank you for this, it really helps.Would you possibly know how I can also stop the value increasing upon stop button being pressed?

Comment: well you can compute the value in stopTimer() and save it

Comment: @Maja I updated the answer with a code sample, if you find it helpful you can accept it and/or upvote